# Multi column exist statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert data to a table from another where data is not already exists

The table I am inserting the data into

```
CREATE TABLE #T(Name VARCHAR(10),Unit INT, Id INT)
INSERT INTO #T
    VALUES('AAA',10,100),('AAB',11,102),('AAC',12,130)
```

The table I am selecting the data from

```
CREATE TABLE #T1(Name VARCHAR(10),TypeId INT,Unit INT, Id INT)
INSERT INTO #T1
VALUES('AAA',3,10,100),('AAA',3,10,106)
```

In this case I want to select `('AAA',3,10,106)` from #T1 because AAA,106 combination not exists in #T

Basically what I want is to populate unique Name and Id combination

I tried below which doesn't seems to work

```
SELECT *
FROM #T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to somehow correlate the two tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM #T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM #T
                 WHERE #T1.Name = #T.Name AND #T1.ID = #T.ID)
```

The above query essentially says: get me those records of table `#T1` which do not have a related record in `#T` having the *same* `Name` *and* `ID` values.

Comment: On the right track but he wanted to insert data into the DB, not select from it

Comment: @Coop He showed a `SELECT` query as a research effort, I tried to present the one that actually works.

Comment: Understood.  My thought was that he demonstrated no knowledge of how to use a subquery to accomplish his goal.  Without including the SELECT statement in a subquery it's useless

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use a insert statement with a subquery.  Something like this:

[SQL Insert Into w/Subquery - Checking If Not Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786101/sql-insert-into-w-subquery-checking-if-not-exists)

Edit:  If you're still stuck, try this--

```
INSERT INTO #T (Name, Unit, Id)
SELECT Name, Unit, Id
FROM #T1 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name, Unit, Id FROM #T
        WHERE #T.Name = #T1.Name AND #T.Unit = #T1.Unit AND #T.Id = #T1.Id)
```